# encode and send data with ASN.1

Tags: c, asn.1

I want to use socket to send an int from the client to the server with ASN.1 . This is the ASN definition

```
Message01 ::= SEQUENCE
        {
          number INTEGER  -- inital integer
        }
```

And this is the C code

```
INTEGER_t clientNumber;
    printf("Enter a number :\n  "); 
    scanf("int *",&clientNumber);
    Message01_t *message1;

    message1 = calloc(1, sizeof(Message01_t));
    message1->number = clientNumber;
      der_encode(&asn_DEF_Message01, message1, 1, 0);
```

I got an error with der_encode

> warning: passing argument 3 of ‘der_encode’ makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast client.c:117: error: incompatible types in assignment

In the example [example ASN.1](http://lionet.info/asn1c/asn1c-usage.html#SECTION02212000000000000000%22example%22) they wrote

```
der_encode(&asn_DEF_Rect, rect,write_stream, ostream);
```

But I don't understand what is write_stream.

**EDIT:**

I tried this

```
static int
write_out(const void *buffer, size_t size, void *app_key) {
     FILE *out_fp = app_key;
    size_t wrote;
    wrote = send( to_server_socket, &buffer, sizeof( buffer ), 0 );

    return (wrote == size) ? 0 : -1;
}

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
```

and

```
der_encode(&asn_DEF_Message01, message1, write_out, 0);
```

But I have an error

```
ndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_asn_DEF_Message01", referenced from:
      _main in cccwTrYO.o
  "_der_encode", referenced from:
      _main in cccwTrYO.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this documentation is terrible.  But there's a clue in the "rectangle" example ...

```
/*
 * This is a custom function which writes the
 * encoded output into some FILE stream.
 */
static int
write_out(const void *buffer, size_t size, void *app_key) {
    FILE *out_fp = app_key;
    size_t wrote;

    wrote = fwrite(buffer, 1, size, out_fp);

    return (wrote == size) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

and then

```
ec = der_encode(&asn_DEF_Rectangle, rectangle, write_out, fp);
```

I deduce from this that the `write_stream` argument is supposed to be a callback function that you write, and the `ostream` argument is supposed to be application-supplied data which is passed verbatim to the callback.  This is a pretty common pattern for callbacks in C.

So you need to write a callback function that writes to your network socket (using `write` or `send`), provide that as `write_stream`, and pass the socket descriptor number as the `ostream`.

Comment: I tried to write th write_stream function but I still have some trouble.I updated my post.

Comment: Your new problem is unrelated to your previous problem; it is simply that you need to tell the compiler to link against the ASN.1 library you are using.  (If you thought you *did* tell it that, move all the `-l` options to the very end of the command line.)  Also, take a moment to reread your modified callback function and think carefully about what it is doing; I see at least two potential problems (not problems that would cause the link error, but problems that may bite you later).

Comment: you mean like that? It don't solve the problem :/ gcc  -o client client.c -I../client/asn

Comment: I don't know enough about this ASN library to know exactly what you need, but it will be something like `-L../client/asn -lasn`.  Note that `-L`, `-l`, and `-I` are three different things; as always, Unix is case sensitive.

Comment: Still don't work , in the documentation he used  cc -I. -o rencode *.c but I still have the error. Maybe the function I wroted is false ?

Comment: Please believe me when I tell you that the only connection between your original problem and your current problem is that they involve the same library.  You should ask a new question about your current problem.

Comment: "in the documentation he used `cc -I. -o rencode *.c` but I still have the error." -- For future reference, the `DPDU` might be the missing piece, therefore: `$ gcc -DPDU=Message01 -I. -o main *.c`.